# How can i make a scrolling Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

How i can make a scrolling Graphe please,

This is my [file](http://grosfi.ch/EnJF7ZtJfEJ)
and this is my [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YXyX.png)

And this is what I have tried so far :

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # plotting
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()
root.title('Plot')


def Plot():
    FilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    Data = pd.read_csv(FilePath, header=None)
    time = Data.iloc[:, 0]
    col = len(Data.columns)
    colAmp = int((col - 1) / 3)

    if col <= 4:
        Amplitude = Data.iloc[::, 1::3]
    else:
        Amplitude = Data.iloc[:, 1:colAmp:1]

    # --------Plot AScan--------#
    fig2, axes2 = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, dpi=100, constrained_layout=True)
    axes2.plot(time, Amplitude)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


btn_pf = Button(root, relief=GROOVE, padx=16, pady=1, text="Plot", command=Plot)
btn_pf.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```